# How to change background image of Dolphin file browser from default white background?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, qt, desktop-background, dolphin

I am using Kubuntu 16.10 which has Dolphin file Manager having default white background. I want to give a custom image as background as there in the desktop.

Comment: Right click on *Desktop > Folder view settings > Wallpapers*

Comment: Sir, it only changes the desktop background not the background of dolphin file manager. @M.Becerra

Comment: Asking for your help too.. @giaosudau

Answer (score 4):

**Qt Style Sheets**

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html :

> Qt Style Sheets are a powerful mechanism that allows you to customize
>   the appearance of widgets...

More:

- Qt Style Sheets Examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html
- Qt Style Sheets Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

**QSS & Dolphin background image**

Older from the KDE Forums - How to set a pattern (image) as a wallpaper on Dolphin?: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=94717

and more:

- Deviantart: http://samuaz.deviantart.com/art/Kde-GaiaSnow-update-4-373661315 -> http://pastebin.com/wEnndQPw
- [SOLVED] Scaled background image using stylesheet: https://forum.qt.io/topic/40151/solved-scaled-background-image-using-stylesheet/2

**Example**

Making backStyle.qss:

```
DolphinViewContainer > DolphinView > QAbstractScrollArea {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-image: url('background.png') 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
```

and starting the Dolphin with the command:

```
dolphin -stylesheet /path/to/myqss/backStyle.qss
```

The result:
[image]

**Note**

The Dolphin is painting every other line with the alternate background color in the details view mode:

[image]

You could change the color but you can't edit the transparency without rebuild of the Dolphin.

Changing the .../src/kitemviews/kitemlistwidget.cpp line 118 from:

```
const QColor backgroundColor = m_styleOption.palette.color(QPalette::AlternateBase);
```

to

```
const QColor backgroundColor = QColor(0, 0, 0, 20);
```

About Qt colors: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-2

[image]

After rebuild:

[image]

Comment: Re. *"The Dolphin is painting every other line with the alternate background color in the details view mode"*, if the alternating color is undesirable, the user can open `System Settings` >`Color` to get to the `Application Color Scheme` window. In there, click on the theme currently being used from the list on the left and then choose `Edit Scheme` near the bottom right. A new window appears titled, for example, `Breeze Dark - System Settings`. Click on the `Colors` tab. On the right of `Color set:`, choose `View` from the dropdown. ...

Comment: There, set `Alternate Background` to be the same as `Normal Background`. Click `Save`. Use a new name for the theme to avoid altering the original Breeze Dark. Close the window. You'll be returned to the first `Applications Color Scheme` window. Click on the theme you just "created" and then click on `Apply` in the lower right corner. Close `System Settings`. Now when Dolphin is opened, there shouldn't be alternating colors for rows in detailed view. This works in Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with kubuntu-backports enabled (Plasma 5.8.7).

Comment: ...What if I want to change the color of the alternating lines and not the opacity? What CSS selector would I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

For quite a while I wanted to make the background of the file area in Dolphin Transparent or Translucent - like the Folder View Widget that I could have on my desktop.
Over the years I messed with different ideas and had a little success, but not the look I wanted to go with my translucent panels and window decorations.

This week I finally achieved a completely translucent 'Dolphin'.
The Bright Red buttons and selections will not be everybody's choise - but they can all be toned down.  The 'Blur Effect' is enabled using GL3.1 in compositing settings in Kubuntu 18.10, but the translucency works and can be adjusted without the blurring using Xrender and in earlier versions of Kubuntu.

[image: Dolphin against a coloured background]

[image: Dolphin against a black and white background to show how the blurring enables the white text to be seen]

This was achieved very simply using the Kvantum theming engine and Kvantum Theme Manager.

While this is not changing the background image in Dolphin, quite a few of us found this topic whilst trying to make a translucent background in Dolphin - so I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share more details>

Comment: Hi, I just wrote an answer, but this site lost it, so instead, I will add a link to Kvantum, which I should have posted in the original - that might help.

https://store.kde.org/p/1005410/